# Changing an array from (rows, columns) to (rows) in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So I have an array in numpy, python, that looks like this:

```
print array
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

However, I want to change this to:

```
print array
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

The original array was:

```
print array
[[ 1]
 [ 2]
 [ 3]
 [ 4]
 [ 5]
 [ 6]
 [ 7]]
```

and I changed it to my array using:

```
x = np.reshape(1, len(array))
```

**How can I complete this change using built-in numpy functions?

I do not want to use loops as I need speed while going through large amounts of data.**

Comment: Please review [How to ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a polite way of saying you have to invest a minimum amount of effort that is not evident here.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem** with the **complete error message and/or stacktrace** and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have the suspicion that you don't actually have to do this transformation. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [np.flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) on your array:

```
>>> x
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
>>> x.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.reshape(x,[-1])`

From the help:

> ```
>  newshape : int or tuple of ints
>         The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If
>         an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length.
>         One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred
>         from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.
>     order : {'C', 'F', 'A'}, optional
>         Read the elements of `a` using this index order, and place the elements
>         into the reshaped array using this index order.  'C' means to
>         read / write the elements using C-like index order, with the last axis index
>         changing fastest, back to the first axis index changing slowest.  'F'
>         means to read / write the elements using Fortran-like index order, with
>         the first index changing fastest, and the last index changing slowest.
>         Note that the 'C' and 'F' options take no account of the memory layout
>         of the underlying array, and only refer to the order of indexing.  'A'
>         means to read / write the elements in Fortran-like index order if `a` is
>         Fortran *contiguous* in memory, C-like order otherwise.
> ```

```
g=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
d=np.reshape(g,(1,-1))
print( d )
>>>[[1 2 3 4 5]]
f=np.reshape(d,[-1])
print( f)
>>>array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```